# search.php not grabbing results from form

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm finding it very hard to return database results with php pdo pagination in wordpress. I have a form on another page that sends the search data to search4.php where I want to display matching rows and have previous|next links. I get no results, and If I echo $search, it just says 'search'
Here is the relevant code so far:

```
//html form on another page
<form method="POST" action="<?www.example.com/search4 ?>">
Search:
<input type="text" name="search"
<input type="submit" name="search" value="search" /></form>


//search4.php relevant code

if(isset($_REQUEST["search"]) && $_REQUEST["search"] != "")
{

$search = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST["search"]);
$pagination->param = "&search=$search";
echo $search;

$pagination->rowCount("SELECT * FROM stories WHERE stories.category LIKE
'%$search%' OR stories.genre = LIKE '%$search%'");
$pagination->config(3, 8);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM stories WHERE stories.category LIKE '%$search%' OR
stories.genre = LIKE '%$search%' ORDER BY SID ASC LIMIT $pagination-
>start_row, $pagination->max_rows";
$query = $connection->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$model = array();
while($rows = $query->fetch())
{
...etc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `<input type=text>` and your `<input type=submit>` has the same name... So button value is overriding your text value... that why is always "search".

change it to:

```
<input type="text" name="search_text"/>
<input type="submit" name="search_button" value="search" />
```

Now, on your search4.php you can access your search text using `$_REQUEST["search_text"]`

PD: You can remove the name attribute on the submit button too.

Comment: Thanks. Although now it doesn't echo anything on search4.php. No results and no echo

Comment: Maybe it was a typo... but `<?www.example.com/search4 ?>` should be: `action="www.example.com/search4.php">`